# What to Do About Flickr?

Tags: discussion

Back when the site was relatively new, I used Flickr to post Pottermore pictures to answer questions, when Pottermore was not copy-able. It's been so long that I don't remember which questions I used the images in, but in downloading my Pottermore file from Flickr there were 54 images in that folder. Gah, that's a lot. How should I handle this? I cannot replace all these images.

Thoughts?

Comment: Doesn't the site use imgur?

Comment: [This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3500+url%3Aflickr.com) turns up 19 of them.

Comment: I don't understand. What's the problem?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Presumably the problem is that if she clears that folder, 54+ of her answers will have dead image links.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the images have now been updated and reside on stack's imgur.

---

## If the links are broken

The same as we do with any broken link:

- Replace where possible. When replacing upload via the sites tool so it goes to stacks imgur and should not die.

  - Maybe you remember the image, get it again. It could also be obvious from the text what the image could be.
  - Check the web archive for the relevant pages: Flickr and SFF in case they have the image.
- If the image can’t be recovered you can always leave the link and add a note that the image can’t be found after the link died.
- If the image is really necessary and can’t be found then it might be more appropriate to remove it all together but this is on a case by case basis.

## If the links aren't broken

It would be best to upload these to stack's imgur through the editor rather than to rely on third party hosting. When editing to do this make note to be wary of the 5 in 15 edit policy and try not to flood the homepage too much.

Comment: What is the 5 in 15 rule?

Comment: @Slytherincess Essentially try not to have more than 5 posts last edited by a single user in the top 15 posts on the home page.

Comment: I wanted to say that when I originally uploaded these images from Flickr, there was no indication that Flickr would go away. Of course any website can go away, so, yeah, using SFF's imigur would have been a better choice. Unfortunately, I can't go back and do it again.

Comment: @Ah, okay. I don't think I would do more than five anyway. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @Slytherincess just to check, before I/we start editing - you give us permission to transfer these screenshots of yours onto SE's Imgur, right?

Comment: For anyone looking at the above comment: [that's a yes](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48546719#48546719). Get editing, people!

Comment: Edited the last three today!